# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException when calling REST API using mockMVC

Tags: rest, mockmvc, http-mock

I am trying to test my API,for which I am calling my API using mockMVC as below:

```
ResultActions resultAction = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users/v1/{userId}",userId)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).headers(header));
```

I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Here is my rest code(using Spring Boot)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/v1/{userId}",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public User getUser(Integer userId) {
    User user = userManagementService.fetchUser(userId);
    return user;
}
```

Can you please suggest what is going wrong here.

Comment: your question is incomplete without code of rest end point at url -  `/paymentbeneficiaries/v1/400744761`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.On putting @EnableWebMvc on my Step definition file,it worked perfectly.